# Copying a certain number of elements from one list to another in python

Tags: python, list

I want to copy the first n no of elements of a list into another list and calculate the standard deviation of the new list

I have tried new_list.append(old_list) but I am not able to perform math operations on the new list.
I need to perform certain operations and I am not allowed to use the statics library

```
def sample_stdev(lst):
    sum,new_sum = 0,0
    new_list = []
    i,j = 0,0

    for x in range(20):         #Copy the first 20 elements
        new_list.append(lst)
        new_sum+= new_list  # didn't work even with new_sum+=new_list[x]
        j += 1
    new_mean = new_sum/j
    for row in new_list:
        i=i+1
        error = row - new_mean
        error_sq = error*error
        sum = sum + error_sq
    b=sum/(i-1)
    std = math.sqrt(b)
    return std

Error: 
new_sum+= new_list[x]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'list'
```

Comment: With `new_list.append(lst)` you want to append a particular element of `lst` and not the whole `lst`. How does one access the element with index `x` from `lst`?

Answer (score 3):

This code:

```
for x in range(20):         #Copy the first 20 elements
    new_list.append(lst)
```

isn't doing what the comment says it's doing; it's appending all of `lst` to `new_list` 20 times, making it a list of lists (but all pointers to the same list).

If you just want to grab the first 20 elements of `lst` you can use the array slicing syntax:

```
new_list = lst[0:20]
```